# How the recursion get expanded

Tags: haskell

I have following function, that do the function composition:

```
applyTimes :: (Eq a, Num a) => a -> (b -> b) -> b -> b
applyTimes 0 f b = b
applyTimes n f b = f . applyTimes (n-1) f $ b
```

and I have following expression:

```
applyTimes 5 (+1) 5
```

Could someone please write out the evaluation?
It is difficult to imaging, how it will be expanded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
applyTimes 5 (+1) 5 =
  (+1) . applyTimes 4 (+1) $ 5

applyTimes 5 (+1) 5 =
  (+1) . (
    (+1) . applyTimes 3 (+1)
  ) $ 5

-- ...

applyTimes 5 (+1) 5 =
  (+1) . (                -- 4
    (+1) . (              -- 3
      (+1) . (            -- 2
        (+1) . (          -- 1
          (+1) . const    -- 0
        )
      )
    )
  ) $ 5
```

I put in `const` because that's what you get after last `applyTimes 0 f` is evaluated.

Or, in flattened form:

```
applyTimes 5 (+1) 5 = (+1) . ((+1) . ((+1) . ((+1) . ((+1) . const))))) $ 5
                    = (+1) .  (+1) .  (+1) .  (+1) .  (+1) . const      $ 5
```

The name can be kind of misleading, since the "apply `f` n times"<sup>1</sup>  is actually done by applying  a function composed of n repetitions of `f`, *once*.

---

What I could also see as confusing is where the actual application happens; perhaps eta-reducing it makes it clearer:

```
applyTimes n f = f . applyTimes (n-1) f
```

---

<sup>1</sup>You could imagine  a perhaps simpler implementation:

```
applyTimes 0 f x = x
applyTimes n f x = f $ applyTimes (n-1) x
```

Comment: the function will be get composed five times to once function right?